# Map Between Two Positive Semidefinite Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Perhaps I was searching for the problem incorrectly, so I hope this isn't a repeat. If so, apologies!

Suppose you have two positive semidefinite matrices $A$ and $B$. Is there a quick or simple way to find another positive semidefinite matrix $W$ such that

$$ W A W^{\dagger} = B $$

where $W^{\dagger}$ is the conjugate transpose of $W$ and $W$ is Hermitian?

(edited to include additional assumptions)

Comment: Sure, we can take $W = \sqrt{B}\sqrt{A}^{-1}$

Comment: Given that $W^{\dagger}$ is the conjugate tranpose, that'd make 
$$ \sqrt{B} \sqrt{A}^{-1} A \sqrt{A}^{-1 \dagger} \sqrt{B}^{\dagger} = B $$
which doesn't satisfy the equality, right?

Comment: What is $W^\dagger$? Conjugate transpose? Do you include symmetry in your definition of positive semidefinite?

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was strict enough, but I suppose yes - given that it is the conjugate transpose, these should be Hermitian matrices.

Comment: I was assuming that positive semidefinite implies Hermitian. Is that not true for your definition?

Comment: Note that $\sqrt A$ is defined to be positive semidefinite and therefore Hermitian. Also, I've fallaciously assume that $A$ is invertible.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom your $W$ isn't hermitian in general...

Comment: Note that no such $W$ exists if $B$ has a greater rank than $A$.

Comment: @user251257 you're right, I forgot that part

Comment: @user251257 but how can you use those eigenbases to build a positive (semi)definite matrix?

Comment: @user251257 Same concern as Omnomnomnom, I don't see any connection between the eigenbases of $A$ and $B$ with $W$. 

Onnomnomnom: If $A$ and $B$ have the same rank, does your solution still apply? It's not clear to me it satisfies the equality ...

Comment: Oh right. My bad. That $W$ should also be hermitian makes it much harder

Comment: @Omnomnomnom or anyone else: It could be written as

$$ W A - B W = 0 $$

but then I would always find the zero matrix as the map W. Maybe I'm just spinning my wheels trying to look at it this way?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're looking for a positive semidefinite $W$?

Comment: @sakanojo it *sort of* applies; I think you can use the pseudo-inverse or do something like that.

Comment: @sakanojo it can only  be written that way if $W$ is **unitary**.  Is **that** what you wanted? Because that's a lot easier (as long as $A,B$ have the same rank).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Maybe I was just too lax in my definition - I thought it may work for a positive semidifinite $W$, but in reality I actually need a unitary matrix $W$. We can restrict $A$ and $B$ to being unitary matrices if we need to as well ...

Comment: @sakanojo what kind of context is this where you can switch between positive definite and unitary?? Anyway, this will work for a unitary $W$ iff $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues.  This will work for some invertible $W$ iff $A$ and $B$ have the same rank.  This will work for some matrix $W$ iff the rank of $A$ is at most the rank of $B$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks for your patience with me! I guess I'm still not seeing how the conjugate transpose of the inverse reduces to the inverse, such that your suggested solutions works above ... If my expression was correct, I don't understand how $ \sqrt{A}^{-1} A \sqrt{A}^{-1 \dagger} $ it would complete the equality.

Comment: Related question: [Find $C$, if $A=CBC$, where $A,B,C$ are symmetric matrices.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284890/find-c-if-a-cbc-where-a-b-c-are-symmetric-matrices/284922#284922)

Comment: Note that $M^{-1 \dagger} = M^{\dagger -1} $

Comment: @user1551 in case you did not see my earlier request, could you please take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1697846/simultaneous-diagonalization-of-two-bilinear-forms where the OP wants to use something he calls "Lagrange Diagonalization" to simultaneously diagonalize two quadratic forms. He did not like my answer.